# Create Multiselect Listview with Xamarin Forms(Xamarin Cross Platform)

Tags: listview, xamarin, multi-select, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement a Listview with Checkbox controll in each item of Listview.If I want to delete two items I will check those two items and click  of delete it should delete.I explored more about this kind of concept but not able to  find single demo example in Github as well.

Programming Language:Xamarin forms not in Xamarin android or Xamain IOS.I already know how to implement in those platforms.But I dont have any sample code at least to for better understanding of "Multiselect and deletion operation in Xamarin Forms"

Comment: I assume you've looked through all [Xamarin.Forms samples](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples)?

Comment: Have you tried using custom cells in your listview?

Answer (score 4):

- Use `SwitchCell` (example here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/ListView/SwitchEntryTwoBinding/twoWayBinding))

or create custom `ViewCell` layout (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance/ - **Custom Cells** chapter)

- Bind `SwitchCell.OnProperty` or `YourCustomViewCell.Checkbox.CheckedProperty` with your `ViewModel.ObservableCollection.IsChecked` property (as in SwitchEntryTwoBinding example)
- Then you could make a `Button` or `ToolbarItem` which calls method that iterates every item in `ViewModel.ObservableCollection` and deletes it if `IsChecked=true`.

Comment: Here is my code for that when I click on the delete button checked rows in Items has to be removed from the listview [Xamarin Forms].

Answer (score 0):

First create a custom cell with a switch (or implement `SwitchCell`). Then bind the switch's value to a bool in your data model. Then, on the button clicked event, a simple Linq query should do the trick.

Make sure your list of items is an `ObservableCollection`, so when you delete items, changes are correctly propagated to the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

We have created a Multi Select ListView control here. It works on all platforms and has no platform specific code.
https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Adapt.Presentation/blob/master/Adapt.Presentation.Standard/Adapt/Presentation/Controls/AdaptListView.cs

There is a full sample included here:
https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Adapt.Presentation.git

This works very well with async behaviour. I.e. you can set the ItemsSource, or the SelectedItems in any order. There is a multi select sample in the repo:
https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Adapt.Presentation.git

There is also a behavior to toggle the selection mode with a button so that you can either jump off to a selected record, or select many records in the listview:
https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Adapt.Presentation/blob/master/Adapt.Presentation.Standard/Adapt/Presentation/Behaviours/AdaptListViewSelectionModeToggleBehavior.cs

This behavior is related because it will allow you to delete selected items from a listview:
https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Adapt.Presentation/blob/master/Adapt.Presentation.Standard/Adapt/Presentation/Behaviours/RemoveFromCollectionBehavior.cs

Unfortunately, this doesn't currently support CheckBoxes, but the functionality works without the need for CheckBoxes, and we may add that feature in future.

Answer (score 0):

**MVVM** approach of how to have a Xamarin.Forms.ListView that holds a set of items that can be selected for deletion. Deletion is initiated through a button command.

**View:**

- Holds `ListView`
- `ListView Cells` are either `SwitchCell` or custom cell with a Control that can bind to a boolean (preferably a Xamarin.Forms.Switch)
- Holds a `Button "Delete Items"`

**Model:**

- Implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface (to update view)
- Holds whatever additional data
- Holds a `public bool ShouldBeDeleted` { ... setter calls PropertyChanged() ...), this will be bound to the `Xamarin.Forms.Switch.IsToggled bindable property`

**ViewModel:**

- is the `BindingContext` of the View
- Holds a `IList/IEnumerable` of instances of the `Model`
- The IList/IEnumerable will be set to the `"ItemsSource"-Property` of the Views ListView
- Holds a command that binds to the `Command property` of the "Delete Items"-Button. This command should call a method that loops through the IList/IEnumerable and removes any item that has ShouldBeDeleted as true.
- use `ObservableCollection` for the ItemList. it updates the View when models are added, removed, or the list is cleared/refreshed